# Why does jQuery.data() not update the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having an issue or possibly a expected result with JQuery's .data() method. Im unsure why when using the element selector the data values are not updated after running the data method. See the screenshot for an example of what im talking about.

[image]

Im unsure why when using the data(key,value) method, it updates the elements data with the expected output. However why is it that it doesnt updated the values html attribute? My knowledge in Javascript is still very limited, but i'd love to know what this is and if i should expect this.

Comment: because it's not supposed to. This is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery reads all `data-attributes` on pageload. It then deals with changes by the `.data()`-function only in it's storage.

To update the "real" HTML-Attribute, you need to manipulate the content like so:

```
$('.selected a span:eq(3)').attr('data-value', 'newValue');
```

Comment: note however that doing so will not change what is already stored in jQuery's .data()

Comment: No, you would have to do changes on both, the attribute and the jQuery's .data(), to do so.

Comment: (to add to @KevinB's 100% correct comment) ...except when you are defining a *new* `data-` attribute that has not been set by `.data()`, since `data-*` values are used as defaults when no `.data()` has been set for some key.

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what i needed to know. Thank you all